# TFS Migration Concerns & Info Needed

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am Currently working on TFS migration from TFS 2015 U3 to TFS 2018 RTM.

Here are my concerns,

1. When i complete the migration, the agents will also migrate or do i
   need to upgrade(Configure) them manually (if so please let me know the process
   to do it)?
2. The extensions (customized: SSIS Deploy in market place) Will also migrate or do we need to migrated them?
   3.Would it be possible to get all the customized data on the TFS project dashboard after the migration?

Answer (score 0):

1. The old build agent is supposed to work after complete upgrade. But it's suggested to upgrade the build agent or deploy new build agents.

Upgrade build agents: Go to build agent pool and select `Update All Agents` item:

[image]

Deploy new agents: This process is the same as you deploy build agents in TFS 2015:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts

2. TFS upgrade is a full data transform, so the extension will also be migrated. But the extension will not be automatically updated when new versions of the extension are published to the Marketplace. It's suggested to uninstall the extensions you had installed in TFS 2015. Then reinstall the latest extensions in TFS 2018.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2017-relnotes#external-extensions-do-not-automatically-upgrade-when-upgrading-tfs

3. It depends on what you have customized. Upgrades to an on-premises TFS can introduce new features that require updates to the objects used to track work. These objects include work item types, categories, and process configuration. Minimizing changes to the workflow for a WIT or the process configuration can help minimize the work you must do when you upgrade your TFS. Check the following link for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#before-you-customize